# Get today's expenses in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to get all today's Expenses divided by type (bills, food etc.) from the Room Database, but my query doesn't work.
How to change query?

```
@Query("SELECT COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(value,0)), 0) FROM expense_table WHERE type = :type + day = strftime('%d', 'now')")
LiveData<Double> getTotalExpenseDay(String type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use "AND" instead of "+", like this:
"SELECT COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(value,0)), 0) FROM expense_table WHERE type = :type AND day = strftime('%d', 'now')"

Comment: Yes, it's probably the '+'. In SQL 'AND' is the operator for adding more than one condition. Since SQL conditions are like Booleans